# Getting MAC address of another host using perl

Tags: perl, arp

I'm trying to find the MAC address of a host if I only have its IP address in perl. I have the following code, but its throwing an error.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Net::ARP;

$mac = Net::ARP::arp_lookup('eth0','192.168.1.9');

print "$mac";
```

When I run the code I get the following error, 
    "SIOCGARP: No such device or address". 
I know the device is the correct one I want to use, and I know the IP address is connected to the network and is valid. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you read the arp table via `/proc/net/arp`?

Comment: Is that address in the same subnet as the host you are using? If it is not then the there will not be an arp table entry for it.

Comment: I found the problem. Turns out I didn't understand what arp_lookup does. I thought it sent out an ARP request packet, but it actually just reads from the ARP table. Once I had the target MAC in my ARP table the above code worked just fine.

Answer (score 1):

i was googling for `SIOCGARP: No such device or address` and i just found this thread here.
by the way i solved this by pinging the target using :

```
use Net::Ping;
#my $target = "SOME TARGET";
my $p = Net::Ping::new->('icmp');
$p->ping($target, 1);
#...
#...
#...
```

hope this could help.
V1R4N64R

Answer (score -2):

Hi you can use this linux commands if you want.

```
arping

arpscan

nmap
```

Comment: the programs have nothing to do with perl.